# How to ls and know the target of symbolic links in one command line?

Tags: unix-shell

I need to get the folder contents in one command line, right now if I do stat or ls, it tells me file type is Symbolic Link but it doesn't tell me if it's a file or a folder.

I'm using this;

```
stat -c '{"name": "%n", "size": "%s", "perms":"%a","type":"%F","user":"%U", "dereference","%N"}' /*;
```

Important point is, i need a one liner and very speedy output. I couldn't get around this doing ls, maybe there is a solution using find, locate etc. Or if u know how to read from mlocatedb ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this which adds another field:

```sh
stat -c '{L"name": "%n", "size": "%s", "perms":"%a","type":"%F","user":"%U", "dereference":"%N"}' /* | 
    sed '/\/\o47\"\}$/ {s/\}/,\"dir\":\"yes\"\}/;b}; s/\}$/,\"dir\":\"no\"\}/'
```

By the way, I changed the comma after "dereference" to a colon.

Answer (score 6):

`ls -l` will show you the target of a link.  Is that what you need?  Another option is `readlink <file>`.

Oops, sorry, didn't read everything there.  How about `ls -lL`.  The `-L` tells ls to dereference the link, so you'll see the target there instead of the link.

Answer (score 4):

`stat` also knows the option `-L` to dereference symlinks. Try your calls with this parameter.

Comment: Is that anything like "defenestrating"?

Comment: Sorry. I've taken a look at a dictionary. I'm not a native english speaker.

Comment: Sorry, just kidding around.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using find with xargs ...something like this

```
find <PATH> -type l | xargs -I{} -t 'find {} -type d;'
```

which will

- find all links
- pass the result to another find which is restricted to subdirs only

You may have to tweak this a bit since I don't know your context, and I don't have a sample set of files that matches your needs to test it on
There is a [very good post here](http://xion.io/post/code/shell-xargs-into-find.html) describing the mechanism